# How to Export million records DynamoDB table as a CSV using Data Pipeline?

Tags: csv, amazon-dynamodb, etl, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a million record DynamoDB table. I am using the Data Pipeline to export the DynamoDb table to S3. But the Data Pipeline exports the table as a group of raw json files in DynamoDB JSON format. After the Data Pipeline ran for an hour, the EMR failed due to timeout exception.

Is there any way to export the DynamoDB table as a CSV and increase the EMR timeout configuration in Data Pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You may check [DynamoDBToCSV](https://github.com/edasque/DynamoDBtoCSV) exporter service. This tool is a simple node project where you have to put your AWS configuration and then after you can run and download all the records from dynamoDB table.